# 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int'

Tags: c, linux

I am getting the error below while doing Linux migration. Line no 25 from the file is below. Please suggest, added my_val.h

```
In file included from ddtc.c:36:
ddtc.h:25: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int'
make: *** [ddtc.o] Error 1
```

ddtc.h

```
18  #pragma ident  "$Id: ddtc.h 2 28-JUN-2014 09:31:15 DDAC$"
19
20  #ifndef _INCL_STRING_FDS_
21  #define _INCL_STRING_FDS_
22
23  #include "my_val.h"
24
25  int stringFDS(char ** s, char * myVar); /* String feeder*/
26
27  #endif
```

my_val.h

```
#ifndef _TYPE_VALUE_INC_
#define _TYPE_VALUE_INC_

/* Return value */

#ifndef RETURN_PASS
#define RETURN_PASS  0
#endif

#ifndef RETURN_DENY
#define RETURN_DENY    -1
#endif

#define RETURN_EOF           1 /* Processing done due to EOF */

#ifndef WIN32
#ifndef TYPEDEF_BOOL_FOR_C
#define TYPEDEF_BOOL_FOR_C

#ifndef bool
typedef int bool
#endif

#ifndef true
#define true 1
#endif

#ifndef false
#define false 0
#endif

#endif /* ndefined TYPEDEF_BOOL_FOR_C */

#endif /* ndefined WIN32 */

#endif /* ndefined _TYPE_VALUE_INC_ */
```

Comment: problem is very probably in `my_val.h`, please paste the last few lines from there.

Comment: This code works fine on Solaris, giving an error when copied to Linux.

Comment: @Anti Haapala, I added my_val.h, please check

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on `typedef int bool`

Comment: You are missing `;` in the typedef.

Comment: Thanks alot Keith Thompson and Havenard.

Comment: notice that `stdbool.h` now has `bool` datatype; funny things might happen bc of this